# Why is my Atmega328p program freezing when I add a function?

Tags: freeze, avr-gcc

I'm trying to create a simple program on an Atmega328p. When I include only the main function it works fine, but adding another function (even without calling it) causes the microcontroller to freeze (the light doesn't blink at all).

I've narrowed it down to simply adding an empty function. The below freezes - by simply commenting out the function it works fine (light blinks).

```
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void){
    DDRB |= (1 << 5);
    PORTB |= (1 << 5);
    while(1){
        PORTB ^= (1 << 5);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }

return 0;
}

void Somerandomcrap(char data){

}
```

```
$ avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p -Os -Wall -DF_CPU=16000000 -I inc/   -c -o src/main.o src/main.c
$ avr-gcc -o main.elf src/main.o
$ avr-objcopy -O ihex main.elf main.hex
$ avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega328p -U flash:w:main.hex

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "main.hex"
avrdude: input file main.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (80 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.16s

avrdude: 80 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against main.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file main.hex:
avrdude: input file main.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: input file main.hex contains 80 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.09s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 80 bytes of flash verified

avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FD, H:DE, L:FF)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - it was because I was passing the MCU type only in the compiler stage, but not in the linker stage.